# Essential Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, rubygems

We're starting to standardise on a Ruby-based testing framework, having had some very good results out of RSpec and Cucumber-based testing recently.  As this is a large enterprise, we're going to attempt to put together a "standard" set of Ruby gems for testing, knowing we're only ever going to get it ~90% right because of the broad mix of technologies being used.

Key technologies we've identified so far that we need to be able to support:

- message transport layers: WebSphere MQ, Tibco (within our test cases, we need to be able to read/write messages & clear queues)
- databases: SQL Server, Oracle, Sybase (we need to be able to do CRUD operations on each of these as part of our test cases)
- user interfaces: Web, .NET, Java/Swing, Silverlight (ideally we'd be able to automate driving each of these UIs through an appropriate interface)

As a starting point, we've decided we want the following set of gems installed (in addition to those that come with Ruby itself):

- cucumber (plus hoe and other dependencies)
- rubywmq (for testing involving WebSphere MQ)
- webrat
- watir (for those cases where webrat won't cut it)
- rails (not so much for Rails itself, but for activerecord and the various DB drivers that come down as dependencies, as well as rake)
- ruby-oci8 (for Oracle)

For Silverlight apps, we hope to be able to test them through IronRuby, but that's very much unknown territory for us at this point.

Two questions:

- any other key gems we've missed?  Stuff that you just can't live without?  What's good/bad/ugly?
- any sources of reference for driving Java/Swing, Silverlight and .NET user interfaces?  I'm aware of the RSpec book, but are there any others out there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good Question man !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add

- [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/). If you use Cucumber, Rspec or ActiveSupport, chances are it will get loaded automatically if installed.
- Test::Unit or RSpec. The first one isn't a GEM, it's a standard Ruby library. Personally I'm a Test::Unit guy rather than a RSpec user, however you might want to give RSpec a try.
- [Shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/tree/master) Shoulda consists of test macros, assertions, and helpers added on to the Test::Unit framework.
- [Remarkable](http://github.com/carlosbrando/remarkable/tree/master) Remarkable is a port of all Shoulda macros to RSpec.

Also you might want to use

- [RCov](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/rcov) to check your LOC

Not strictly related to tests but always about code quality:

- [Flay](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flay.html) analyzes ruby code for structural similarities.
- [Flog](http://ruby.sadi.st/Flog.html) shows you the most torturous code you wrote.
- [Reek](http://silkandspinach.net/2008/09/23/reek-a-code-smells-detector-for-ruby/) a code smells detector for ruby
- [Roodi](http://roodi.rubyforge.org/) parses your Ruby code and warns you about design issues you have based on the checks that is has configured.

Comment: Great answer - I've used Mocha before, but most of the rest are new to me.  Thanks you for taking the time to create this list

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri for parsing XML is another one

Comment: AFAIK, webrat depends on Nokogiri so you'll get it installed when you install webrat.

Answer (score 1):

Zentest, it is very Important for testing

Also  **Mongrel**  or  **Passenger** for application deployment

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I should've described our situation a bit more clearly.  We don't do Ruby development (at this stage); we're just using Ruby to test our Java/.NET applications.

Answer (score 1):

A few very nice gems for irb/rails console...

- [**Pry**](https://github.com/pry/pry) - gives you the ability to `ls`, `cd` around available objects. Show the source for methods, display rails models... and a significant amount of other features
- [**irbtools**](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools) - a bunch of tools collected together (including wirb, hirb, interactive_editor (let's you open emacs, vim etc.), coderay, ... list on the github page)